# Location prop undefined on refresh (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm sending an object with a couple of params through the "to" prop on my Link from react-router-dom. Initially, when the link is clicked, the data is fine and the props have their value. Once I refresh they are undefined.

Heres the Link...

```
let newTo = {
     pathname: `/poke/${name}`,
    param1: name
}
const { name } = this.props;
<Link style={viewBtn} to={newTo}>View</Link>
```

Heres the route if it matters...

```
<Route path="/poke/:pokemon" component={PokeSummary} />
```

Heres the code on my other component receiving the prop...

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        paramName: props.location.param1,
        pokemon: {
            id: 0,
            name: '',
        },
        isLoading: false
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData(this.state.paramName)
}

fetchData = (nameP) => {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${nameP}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
            pokemon: {
                id: data.id,
                name: data.name,
            }
        }, () => {console.log(this.state.pokemon)}))
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use `props.match.params.pokemon` instead of passing the param like so, since if the user is not redirected through your link and navigates to the url directly, these internal states will not be available

Comment: Ah dude you're my favorite person right now, that worked. Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.